# Unable to create and map through an array using new Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to map some elements based on an arbitrary length.

I haven't been able to find anything online, but I'd like to do something like:

```
new Array(5).map(num => <input />)
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

A user would input a number, and then that many input fields should render.

What am I doing wrong here?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-forest-51h4o?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) the array before mapping, as [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) ignores empty slots.

```
new Array(5).fill().map(num => <input />)
```

However, [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) would be more suitable in this case.

```
Array.from({length: 5}, ()=> <input />)
```

Answer (score 1):

use `fill` then map the array

```
new Array(5).fill().map(num => <input />)
```

or you could use `Array.from`

```
Array.from(Array(5), ()=> <input />)
```